# Forecast next time series in R predict value

Tags: time-series

Using R command `predict`, if the predict value is almost same, what can I do next step?

For example,

A time series model is determined as AR(1) model, and I predict the next value but it's very suspicious. (Data's period=12 and predict period=12 month, 1 year)

Example data is below.

Is that means only first few data available?
And I can forecast just next few time period?

```
2459853
2481777
2496666
2506778
2513645
2518309
2521476
2523627
2525088
2526080
2526754
2527211
```

EDIT:

First of all, I thinks there is some misunderstanding about example data.

Below is original data and first data was predicted value.(forecasted by AR(1) model)

Now My question is same as first. 
Thanks.

> 2935833
>   2622529
>   2719635
>   2625179
>   2311187
>   2101758
>   2552638
>   2883423
>   3128904
>   2959348
>   2759000
>   2233755
>   2560858
>   2548821
>   2625675
>   2326076
>   1662956
>   1772409
>   1797275
>   2639852
>   2799990
>   3133285
>   2438296
>   2583766
>   2610157
>   2493415
>   2094163
>   2174301
>   2283420
>   2505128
>   2873785
>   2339727
>   2985829
>   3037351
>   1828265
>   1038562
>   1474727
>   1523331
>   2122667
>   2571006
>   2252161
>   2422347
>   2155973
>   2294976
>   2809652
>   2436293
>   2561852
>   2199544
>   2674423
>   2551363
>   3110508
>   3177925
>   3046952
>   2850904
>   3002830
>   2910913
>   2809172
>   3136842
>   3355368
>   3604565
>   3013310
>   3125751
>   2548605
>   2646575
>   2231458
>   1962095
>   1958019
>   2143073
>   2305966
>   2620302
>   2356447
>   2427571

Comment: I can reproduce these data *exactly,* assuming they are rounded to the nearest integer.  The formula is $y = 2528180 - \exp(11.519 -0.386936x)$, $x=1,2,\ldots,12$.  This formula forecasts the next value as $2527522$.

Answer (score 7):

Here is the plot of your data:

[image]

It is clear then, that it is probably not generated by statistical model. It is then not surprising that AR(1) predictions look suspicious. I suspect that some S-curve type function can be perfectly fitted to your data.

**Update**

**Note** What comes below is complement to IrishStat answer with R code illustrations.

On the other hand, as IrishStat pointed out, AR(1) model is useful here. In fact we have the following:

```
> bb<- structure(list(V1 = c(2459853L, 2481777L, 2496666L, 2506778L, 
2513645L, 2518309L, 2521476L, 2523627L, 2525088L, 2526080L, 2526754L, 
2527211L), index = 1:12, lV1 = c(NA, 2459853L, 2481777L, 2496666L, 
2506778L, 2513645L, 2518309L, 2521476L, 2523627L, 2525088L, 2526080L, 
2526754L)), .Names = c("V1", "index", "lV1"), row.names = c(NA, 
-12L), class = "data.frame")

> summary(lm(V1~lV1,data=bb))

Call:
lm(formula = V1 ~ lV1, data = bb)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-0.44873 -0.16852  0.00065  0.20665  0.28504 

Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) 8.112e+05  9.046e+00   89681   <2e-16 ***
lV1         6.791e-01  3.605e-06  188386   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1 

Residual standard error: 0.246 on 9 degrees of freedom
  (1 observation deleted due to missingness)
Multiple R-squared:     1,  Adjusted R-squared:     1 
F-statistic: 3.549e+10 on 1 and 9 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

So we have a perfect fit (in the precision of original data):

```
> fitted(lm(V1~lV1,data=bb))-bb$V1[-1]
            2             3             4             5             6 
-0.0431514978  0.2081317329 -0.2217918197  0.1431496162 -0.2695231647 
            7             8             9            10            11 
 0.1938952347 -0.0006489181 -0.1915123449  0.0177617292 -0.2850446492 
           12 
 0.4487340818
```

The forecast  for future values is :

$$Y_{t+h}=\alpha(1+\rho+...+\rho^{h-1})+\rho^hY_t$$

where $Y_t$ is the last point of the data, $h$ -- the forecasting horizon, and $\alpha$ and $\rho$ are estimated coefficients:

```
> coef(lm(V1~lV1,data=bb))
 (Intercept)          lV1 
8.112164e+05 6.791302e-01
```

Since your data is without stochastic error, the usual methods might behave strangely, which is illustrated by the following code:

```
> auto.arima(ts(bb$V1))
Series: ts(bb$V1) 
ARIMA(2,2,1)                    

Coefficients:
         ar1      ar2     ma1
      1.9691  -0.9691  0.8809
s.e.     NaN      NaN     NaN

sigma^2 estimated as 37898:  log likelihood=-70.44
AIC=148.88   AICc=156.88   BIC=150.09
```

Or even

```
> arima(ts(bb$V1),order=c(1,0,0))
Series: ts(bb$V1) 
ARIMA(1,0,0) with non-zero mean 

Coefficients:
         ar1   intercept
      0.9569  2497162.58
s.e.  0.0575    27950.09

sigma^2 estimated as 80110030:  log likelihood=-127.46
AIC=260.92   AICc=263.92   BIC=262.37
```

As you see the AR(1) coefficient is estimated incorrectly. The fit is also very bad compared to OLS fit:

```
> ts(bb$V1)-fitted(arima(ts(bb$V1),order=c(1,0,0)))
Time Series:
Start = 1 
End = 12 
Frequency = 1 
 [1] -10830.884  20317.315  14226.441  10090.616   7281.075   5373.793
 [7]   4077.641   3198.024   2600.654   2194.570   1919.289   1731.313
```

The precise explanation why is that can be complicated, but the general rule is, that algorithms might perform poorly on corner cases (zero errors in this case).

Comment: (+1) **Step 1**: Plot your data.

Comment: Re the edits: note that this AR(1) model is identical to the fit I reported, because the lV1 coefficient of `6.7913E-01` equals $\exp(-0.386936)$ (the rate coefficient in my fit).  Whether one should view the data as autoregressive or as following an exponential really depends on how the data are generated and the purpose of the predictions.

Answer (score 3):

Your data can be modelled with an AR(1) which can flexibly approximate many different kinds of time series data. All models are wrong some are useful said Prof. Box. The model

```
     MODEL COMPONENT          LAG    COEFF     STANDARD      P       T   

  #                          (BOP)              ERROR      VALUE   VALUE    


1CONSTANT                          .811E+06     8.18       .0000  9999.99

2Autoregressive-Factor #  1    1   .679         .100       .0000     6.79
```

FINAL REPORT

MODEL STATISTICS AND EQUATION FOR THE CURRENT EQUATION (DETAILS FOLLOW).

Estimation/Diagnostic Checking for Variable Y    se

Number of Residuals (R)        =n                         11

Number of Degrees of Freedom   =n-m                        9

Residual Mean                  =Sum R / n                .000000

Sum of Squares                 =Sum R**2                 .544708

Variance                       =SOS/(n)                  .453923E-01

Adjusted Variance              =SOS/(n-m)                .605231E-01

Standard Deviation RMSE        =SQRT(Adj Var)            .246014

Standard Error of the Mean     =Standard Dev/ (n-m)      .820048E-01

Mean / its Standard Error      =Mean/SEM                 .000000

Mean Absolute Deviation        =Sum(ABS(R))/n            .183942

AIC Value ( Uses var )         =nln  +2m                -30.0165

SBC Value ( Uses var )         =nln  +m*lnn             -29.2207

BIC Value ( Uses var )         =see Wei p153             207.690

R Square                       =                         1.00000

The graph of the actual/fit and forecasts is [image] . The plot of the residuals from this model suggest a non-random error term leading to some augmentation [image] as does the ACF of the errors . I would think that some slight augmentation might be needed to approximate what to me is a clearly determinstic series . Note that the forecast 'is similar" to the last value thus having approached an assymptotic value which is a characteristic of all non-differenced AR models. The forecasts are presented here[image] . Here is the ACF of the model errors [image]

The simplicity of an auto-regressive model can be seen when it is expressed as a simple ols model.

MODEL EXPRESSED AS AN XARMAX

Y[t] =   a[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zbIuh.jpg)Y[t-1] + ... + a[p]Y[t-p]

```
   + w[0]X[t-0] + ... + w[r]X[t-r] 

   + b[1]a[t-1] + ... + b[q]a[t-q]  

   + constant
```

THE RIGHT-HAND SIDE CONSTANT IS:                                             811220.

Y                       1             .679130  *  Y(   12 )= 2527211.000000= 1716305.403967

```
                                           NET PREDICTION FOR Y(   13 )= 2527521.811269
```

Comment: +1, for noticing that this is AR(1) with zero error. Did your software detected that automatically, or did you ask to fit the AR(1) regression?

Comment: :mpiktas When I ran it automatically it suggested a double difference with an AR(1) and a constant. This augmented model gave very similar forecasts and might have been a "slight overkill" with just 12 data points. It did however suggest to me that the residuals from a simple AR(1) might have structure and indeed they do.

Comment: :mpkitas One of your models ARIMA(2,2,1)                    

         ar1      ar2     ma1
      1.9691  -0.9691  0.8809 can be algebraically simplified as follow  (1-2B +1B**2)/(1-B) to (1-B) or (1-phiB) . What you received as a solution had redundant structure i.e. cancelling structure.

Comment: :mpkitas To be clear   1.9691 approx =  2.0  ;  -.9691 approx =    -1.0 ; .8809 approx = 1.0 . The problem with AIC criteria optimzation is that if the true model = mean + a(t) this can be confused with an arima model (1,0,1) where phi=.8 and ma1=.8 . In your case you received an AR(2) and an MA(1) while an AR(1) would have sufficed.

Answer (score 0):

Now that your question has been rephrased, we have [image: a plot of the original data. A keen eye can easily detect some pulses (1 time unusual values ) and upon a closer examination a possible double shift in the level of the series in the most recent data] . We proceed to automatically identify ( this step is possible with a lot of programs ) the underylying model using [image: the ACF of the original data] which leads to [image: an AR(1) model]. This model generates a set of residuals [image]. These residuals visually have a clear lack of normality as a there are pulses and two level shifts (clumps or residuals) near the end. The ACF of these residuals is downward biased by the abnormal values and thus can be classified as an "alice in wonderland test". [image]. We can now look to identify simultaneously bot the ARIMA structure and any Intervention Variables that might need to be incorporated to provide a robust estimate of the ARIMA coefficients.[image: actual/fit/forecast with integrated model]. The equation for this model is [image: estimated model parameters] . Note that the two level shifts are at period 49 and 64 with one time unusual points at 35,36,37,38 { a patch of pulses} and 60. Recall that there are 72 values in the history of the series. Note that the robustly estimated AR(1) coefficient is .400 versus the .681 from the simple original model. Note that the "two clusters of similar values" that were identified incorrectly enhanced i.e. made larger the AR(1) coefficient since the values in each of the two clusters are very predictable lag 1.  A plot of the residuals from this augmented model is shown [image] with an ACF of [image]. Now with respect to the forecasts from this complete model. They are based upon the level shifts, the seasonal pulse and the AR(1) coefficient.[image] As can be seen the forecasts reach a limiting value within a few periods.